# Cannot POST /php/enviar.php

Tags: php, angular

Si alguién me pudierá ayudar se lo agradecería bastante. Tengo un problema con Angular 10, el cuál es que yo tengo un blog personal y contiene una sección de contacto, la cuál rellenas los campos input. Una vez hecho eso envias esos datos a un correo electrónico mediante PHP, antés en mi blog SIN Angular me funcionaba a la perfección y ahora me da un error

Código PHP:

```
  <?php
 $destino = "ivaylocontacta@gmail.com";
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
 $correo = $_POST["correo"];
 $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
 $contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre . "\nApellidos: " . $apellidos . "\nCorreo: " . $correo . "\nMensaje: " . $mensaje;
 mail($destino,"Contacto", $contenido);
?>
```

Código HTML:

```
<div class="contenedor">
            <h3 id="contacto">Contáctame</h3>
            <hr id="hr">
            <form action="../../../../php/enviar.php" method="POST">   
                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputBox">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" required class="input">
                            <span class="text">Nombre</span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputBox">
                            <input type="text" name="apellidos" required class="input">
                            <span class="text">Apellidos</span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                <div class="row100">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox">
                        <input type="email" name="correo" required class="input">
                        <span class="text">Gmail</span>
                        <span class="line"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row100">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="inputBox textarea">
                        <textarea name="mensaje" required></textarea>
                        <span class="text">Escribe aqui tu mensaje...</span>
                        <span class="line"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row100">
              <div class="col">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="boton" class="env">
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Error:

```
Cannot POST /php/enviar.php
```

Comment: Te hizo falta el mensaje de error

Comment: @BetaM Dónde? Es que no llevo mucho con Angular-

Comment: Se refiere a que no pusiste cuál es el error que te marca php o angular.

Comment: @EdgarGc Ah! Disculpa, me pone lo siguiente:        Cannot POST /php/enviar.php

Comment: Demasiados `..` en el action? Que sucede si colocas la dirección absoluta en vez de por referencia?

Comment: @eftshift0 Da el mismo error, es que Angular no esta preparado para php, pero hay una forma de hacer que funcione la cuál no encuentro.

Comment: El error no tiene que ver con Angular, al menos lo provisto en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestras no tiene nada de Angular. Prueba a poner una ruta absoluta en el action. Prueba a hacer debug en el "enviar.php", para comprobar que recibes los valores de los campos del form.

Comment: Tu respuesta no cumple las características de respuestas se ata más a un comentario.